# I can't install weblogic 12c on Mac M1

Tags: macos, weblogic12c, apple-m1

I bought my mac m1, but I could not install weblogic 12c, I installed java 8 and when I run the following code in the terminal with rosetta

```
java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
```

I get the following error

```
The initiator log file is /private/var/folders/km/tqp3cxcs3jg03bf9c3vgwcjh0000gn/T/OraInstall2021-12-01_01-10-06PM/launcher2021-12-01_01-10-06PM.log.

Extracting files .....

This Installer must be run using a Java Development Kit (JDK) pero /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home it is not a valid JDK.
```

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to install weblogic, you need to export your variables before Run the jar file, at least the Java_home

```
 export JAVA_HOME
 export MW_HOME
 export USER_MEM_ARGS
```